# Can I change the color of a Pixel on the screen?

Tags: c#, xna

I have a paint program that I want to change a specific pixel when you click. How can I do this?

I know that I can create a Color[] of the background image but I need it to update rapidly while the screen is changing

Comment: Going to need to know more about what your program is doing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For C#/XNA, you can create a dynamic texture buffer, and a bitmap image in CPU memory that you copy to the GPU dynamic buffer whenever changes are made... The bitmap class has methods for manipulating pixels so the only part you are really left to figure out is how to map GPU memory and copy the bitmap to the texture buffer. This copy operation is fairly fast.. we use a similar technique to get our HTML HUD to display in our game engine (not XNA based unfortunately) and even with updates every frame we are still over 60fps.

Comment: interesting -- a down vote with no comment as to why.. hmmmmm

Comment: I'm guessing it's because the voter thought that your answer is too abstract; using non-XNA terminology; and without any actual code. That it also has a **non-XNA** lineage does not help either. Finally updating a buffer of reasonable size by the `CPU` only to be sent to the GPU `every frame` is inefficient.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't meant for asking for code. It's meant for answers. Nothing more or less. If that answer includes code, it's probably because it makes sense to have, but it's not a requirement. Long story short, what OP asks cannot be done using XNA-only technologies, and what @Ascendion said is the closest he's going to get.

Comment: And I certainly included enough key terms that the OP can google search examples that do what I'm describing... As for buffer update rates, I was describing what is POSSIBLE, a pixel editing application would probably update MUCH less often than that unless the user is painting with a brush, in which case per-frame updates are very possible. It may be inefficient but there really isn't much in the way of alternative methods to get a dynamic bitmap on the CPU into a texture buffer on the GPU.

Comment: I noted the non-XNA lineage of my HUD code because I haven't used XNA for years... but I am working with DirectX which is the same underlying technology and I know XNA supports dynamic texture updates at some level.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard _"Long story short, what OP asks cannot be done using XNA-only technologies"_ - Incorrect.  Can be done by either `RenderTarget` or drawing a quad even though XNA got rid of point sprites